# How to configure a Firebird Database to run in memory

Tags: sql, memory, firebird

I'm running a software called Fishbowl inventory and it is running on a firebird database (Windows server 2003) at this time the fishbowl software is running extremely slow when more then one user accesses the software. I'm thinking I maybe able to speed up the application by forcing the database to run "In Memory". However I can not find documentation on how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.
Robert

Comment: Which middleware you use to connect Firebird ?

Comment: Good question, along with near-dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180616/firebird-database-tuning-for-multiprocessor, but belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

Firebird does not have memory tables - they may or may not be added in future versions (>3) but certainly not in the upcoming 2.5. There can be any other number of reasons why your software is slow with multiple users; however, Firebird itself has pretty good concurrency, so make sure you find the actual bottleneck first.

Comment: The "in memory" was within quotes, so I assume Robert want's to be able to page as much of the database in memory as possible. This can be done by setting some properties in the firebird.conf file. Look at DefaultDbCachePages, but the file is pretty self explanantory.

Comment: Starting with Version 2.5.1 Firebird now has in-memory tables.

They are called GTT - Global Temporary Table. Their content is connection-local, clears on disconnect or on commit, and database file should still rely on disc - the nuisance, truly.

But the table, wel..., in-memory table does exist :-)

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Holger. Find the bottleneck first.
[Sinática Monitor](http://www.sinatica.com/index.php/en/) may help you.

Comment: * Which version of firebird ? – 2.1.3.

*Which middleware you use to connect Firebird ? Java.

*Good question, along with near-dupe stackoverflow.com/questions/2180616/…, but belongs on serverfault.com – I will place it there as well.

Comment: *Make sure you find the actual bottleneck first - great point, , I have been working to find it. I will look at sinatica, Any other tips?

*The "in memory" was within quotes, so I assume Robert want's to be able to page as much of the database in memory as possible. This can be done by setting some properties in the firebird.conf file. Look at DefaultDbCachePages, but the file is pretty self explanantory. – I will do that thank.

Answer (score 0):

I had read an article some time ago, from someone who did a memory drive (like in old DOS) and ran a Database there. The problem is if anything fails, you lose everything. You should do backups very often to ensure a minimum of security.

Not a good idea at all I think.

Answer (score 0):

In-memory tables are nice either for OLAP (when data is not changing) or for temporary internal data storage.
In both cases data loss is not danger.

Pity that FB has no in-memory mode. I think about using SQLite as result.

As for caching, i think simple parallel thread that reads all the blocks of database file would make it in-memory - in OS cache if OS has enough memory.

But i also think, that OS already cached as much of DB file as it could and agressive forcing to cache would make overall performance even worse.