# Firebird database tuning for multiprocessor

Tags: sql, firebird, performance

I'm running a software called Fishbowl inventory and it is running on a Firebird database (Windows Server 2003). At this time the Fishbowl software is running extremely slow when more then one user accesses the software. I'm wondering if anyone could provide some information on tuning the database or best practices? We are currently running a Dell PowerEdge 2700 dual quad core with 4 gig's of RAM.

Comment: Good question, along with near-dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179902/how-to-configure-a-firebird-database-to-run-in-memory, but belongs on serverfault.com at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

I do report development for Fishbowl Inventory (2009.1-2010.2) and my business partner is a Fishbowl VAR. We have dealt with customers with slow databases. oGive me a shout at ilopez at fishbowlreports dot com

It is odd that your server with those specs is showing lag, but It is not unheard of.

Top Three Things To Keep In mind

1) Database Size - The larger the db, the more rows it has to deal with when working on reports/updates, etc.
2) Activities - Certain activities pound on the server
3) Version - The newer fishbowl versions have additional indexes on the tables, which allow faster queries

In my experience most of the tasks increase in time linearly by the work done. see: http://www.fishbowlinventory.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=16&p=5240 - I did some benchmarking on Fishbowl Inventory 2009.3, hope to do the same in Fishbowl 2010.2 (Once it is released).

-Israel

Comment: Which version of Firebird use Fishbowl ?

Comment: As of Fishbowl 2010.1 - WI-V2.1.1.17910 or Firebird 2.1 ... and seems to have not changed since 2009.2

Comment: And it uses Super Server when on a Single CPU like a Virtual Machine, and then classic when on a multicore machine.

Comment: Israel, I have emailed you but have not received a reply as of yet. I'm interested to speak with you about your experiences and your benchmark tests. My email is Rob at crwefixit dot com
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For good tuning information on Firebird database: look at the documentation you can find on [www.ibphoenix.com](http://www.ibphoenix.com).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not from the Firebird Database. IBPhoenix can help you but you also have to ask your Fishbowl reseller.

- First thing: choosing between [Firebird SuperServer or Firebird ClassicServer](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/qsg15-classic-or-super.html)
- Increase cache for database

other interesting links :

- https://www.ibphoenix.com
- http://www.ibsurgeon.com/knowledgebase/
- http://www.sinatica.com/

Comment: Thanks I will check out the links.

My company is the reseller for the application and thus far the vendor has been no help.

How do I increase the cache, is that in the firebird.conf file under DefaultDbCachePages? and what would be recommended?

Thanks

Comment: if you are using SuperServer : you can increase DefaultDbCachePages in firebird.conf or make change in your database with gfix command http://www.destructor.de/firebird/gfix.htm

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [Firebird Performance in Detail](http://videos.firebirddevelopersday.com/) video from Dmitry Yemanov (chief of Firebird development team). Also, if you are using SuperServer, make sure that FB is attached to a single CPU/core (check CPUAffinity parameter in firebird.conf).

Answer (score 0):

Usually. A bad transaction handling from client part, produce a lot o record versioning. Extract using gstat statitistical data and look for "total version" for each table. Ideal value is 0 for every table. When total  version is greather than total efectives records, we are in trouble.